# Issue using window.postMessage in Firefox OS privileged app

Tags: firefox-os

We are developing an HTML5 gaming platform which we want to port to Firefox OS as a packaged app.  We have a social feature that integrates with Facebook and defining the `redirects`, `origin` and `"type": "privileged"` in the app manifest works for us. However, we faced another problem. The games are loaded in an `iframe` and the communication mechanism that we use to send messages between the games and the platform is window.postMessage, which is blocked when we set the `"type": "privileged"` in the app manifest (tested on Firefox OS Simulator 1.2 and 1.3). We are aware that this must be due to a security restriction, but is there a way to surpass it?

Any advice will be greatly appreciated.
Thank you.

Comment: [My privileged App](https://github.com/kazhik/Hayate) can use postMessage. What do you specify as the second argument(targetOrigin) of postMessage?

Comment: Thank you very much for the reply and for your app example. We had a chance to test our platform on an actual device running Firefox OS 1.3 and it turns out that the problem is not because of `postMessage`, but because we violate the CSP restrictions of the privileged apps by having inline scripts.

Comment: Glad you fixed it, can you post an answer, and accept it so this question will be marked as answered please.